# how to set combobox default value in wpf using binding in mvvm when manually setting combobox items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am using mvvm in wpf. I am setting a form to update user data. I have a combobox to select gender of user. i have added combobox items manually in source. when loading data to form all fields other fields are displaying correctly. but combobox is not displaying anything. I have used twoWay binding and the values i am selecting from form are getting in the viewModel.I have been searching for hours and found many similar problem, but nothing worked for me. I am inserting my code segment bellow. Please give me a solution.

```
<ComboBox 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployees.gender, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEmployees.gender, Mode=TwoWay}"
    >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Male"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Female"/>
</ComboBox>
```

my viewModel code is as bellow

```
class EmployeesModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private iServiceClient serviceClient = new iServiceClient();
    public EmployeesModel()
    {
        this.RefreshEmployees();
    }

    private void RefreshEmployees()
    {
        this.serviceClient.GetAllEmployeesCompleted += (s, e) =>
          {
              this.employees = e.Result;
          };

        this.serviceClient.GetAllEmployeesAsync();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Employee> employees;
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get
        {
            return this.employees;
        }
        set
        {
            this.employees = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
    }

    private Employee selectedEmployees;
    public Employee SelectedEmployees
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedEmployees;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedEmployees = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployees");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

and SelectedEmployees class is

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string post { get; set; }
    public string salaryType { get; set; }
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
    public string docname { get; set; }
    public int validit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your view model code, esp the binding members?

Comment: What is the datatype for gender?

Comment: The items are comboboxitems. I wonder what sort of an object ends up as selecteditem.

Comment: @Andy Should be a `string`

Comment: Nope.  It's a comboboxitem. This is likely his problem. Or one of em anyhow. Hence my question.

Comment: @Andy Hmm. You are right!

Comment: @Andy 'gender' is a string

Comment: @PaulGibson i have added my viewModel code above.

Comment: I know that you have implemented Andy's answer below, but the MVVM style might suggest that your combo box not be a static resource, rather it should be a list of the distinct entries in your database, bound to a collection in the VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that SelectedEmployees.gender is not type comboboxitem.
Taking the shortcut of creating comboboxitems directly in the combobox is a bad move.

When I do:

```
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWIndowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="Genders">
        <sys:String>Male</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Female</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox 
     SelectedItem="{Binding gender, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource Genders}"
        />
</Grid>
```

I get a string instead of a comboboxitem in my bound gender.
You probably want something rather more like that.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. i made this changes and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best approach, particularly if you mean to learn MVVM: Use an enum type for Gender. "LOL" is never a valid gender so don't let anybody try to use it. Populate the ComboBox by binding it to a static collection. Initialize `SelectedEmployees.gender` to the value you want to be the default and the binding will take care of the rest.

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployees.gender}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEmployees.Genders}"
    />
```

C#

```
public class SelectedEmployeesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /* ...other stuff... */

    private Gender _gender = Gender.Male;
    public Gender gender
    {
        get { return _gender; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _gender)
            {
                _gender = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male, Female
}

public static class EnumValues
{
    public static IEnumerable<Gender> Genders => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)).Cast<Gender>();
}
```

---

There are other approaches. I advise against going with a string, but this is illustrative at least:

```
    private String _gender = "Male";
    public String gender
    {
        get { return _gender; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _gender)
            {
                _gender = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Does your `SelectedEmployees` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and does `SelectedEmployees.gender` raise `PropertyChanged` when its value changes?

Get rid of `Mode=TwoWay` on the binding; you don't need to do that explicitly. It's the default for any binding you put on `ComboBox.SelectedValue` or on `ComboBox.SelectedItem`.

As Andy pointed out in comments, your SelectedValue and SelectedItem are both going to be instances of `ComboBoxItem`, because that's how you populated your ComboBox. The string you want is in the Content property of the ComboBoxItems, so use `SelectedValuePath` to tell the ComboBox about that, and bind to the `SelectedValue` property. `SelectedItem` will be the `ComboBoxItem` itself, which is useless to you.

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEmployees.gender}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Content"
    >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" />
</ComboBox>
```

Here's another approach: Populate the ComboBox with strings.

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployees.gender}" 
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    >
    <sys:String>Male</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Female</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

See Andy's answer for yet another way to populate the ComboBox with strings via `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Because the OP mentions using mvvvm I think the last approach is the most appropriate.  Kudos on a really complete answer to a less than complete question :)